# BNG Locator ArcGIS does not work

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geocoding

I am trying to use the bng locator in ArcGIS Desktop. Unfortunately, I am not very successful. I follow following steps:

ArcGIS Desktop - ArcMap

1. Open the Catalog window
2. Expand the GIS Servers Folder and select Add ArcGIS Server
3. In the wizard, choose Use GIS Services
4. Click Next
5. Enter https://datahub.esriuk.com/arcgis/services or http://datahub.esriuk.com/arcgis/services (no authentication details are required)
6. Click Finish
7. Select the new server and choose a locator from the list.

I can add the server to ArcCatalog and I can see it in the Address Locator list. Unfortunately, after entering for example: SE338191 I get information that no address has been found. [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://datahub.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/gb_locators/bng_locator/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?BNG=SE338191&f=pjson is providing the correct information back.

Comment: note the current version supported is 'Current Version: 10.6' http://datahub.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/ are you on ArcGIS 10.6?

Comment: I am using 10.3.1